# style 2nd element on the page with same class

Tags: css

Hello is there a way with css to style the 2nd element on page with the same class slightly differently to the first.

For example I have two ul's on a page with a class of topbardropdownmenu. I want to give the 2nd ul a differen't background to the first. Is there a way to do this with out altering the html?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What holds the `<ul>` elements? I'll assume a `<div id = "lists">`

```
/* First element */
div > ul.topbardropdownmenu:first-child{

}

/* Rest of the elements */
div > ul.topbardropdownmenu{

}
```

...alternatively

`div > ul.topbardropdownmenu:not(:first-child)`

Comment: :first-child doesn't work in IE, so you may need to use server code or javascript to fix this.

Answer (score 19):

You can do it with the `:nth-child()` pseudo-selector. It is CSS3 though, and not supported in some browsers (e.g. <=IE8 & <=FF3.0 doesnt support it).

```
.topbardropdownmenu:nth-child(2) { background: #FF0000; }
```

You could do it with JavaScript in a cross-browser compatible way though, if that's an option for you.

Answer (score 5):

It depends which browsers your users are using, you might be able to use the [`nth-of-type`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthoftype) css pseudo-selector:

```
ul.topbardropdownmenu:nth-of-type(2) {
   /* styles the second ul of class=topbardropdownmenu
}
```

If there's a particular pattern to the occurrence of these `ul` elements, you could use descendant and/or sibling selectors:

```
div > ul.topbardropdownmenu {
  /* styles all ul.topbardropdownmenu that are the immediate descendants of a div */
}

p + ul.topbardropdownmenu {
  /* styles all ul.topbardropdownmenu that immediately follow a p */
}
```

Comment: When you say `it depends on which browsers`, which browsers are your referring to? Which ones will not support this?

Comment: I believe all browsers support `:nth-of-type()` now, but this answer was written eleven - near enough twelve - years ago. Things have vastly improved since.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the quick reply on a post nearly as old as me 

Answer (score 2):

Look at the CSS3 [nth-child() pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo).

Answer (score -2):

You can use :nth-child http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/ but IE may struggle with it. Consider this jQuery alternative:

```
$(".class").eq(1).css();
```

http://api.jquery.com/eq/